# Multi-way clustered standard errors in R survey package

Tags: r, statistics, survey

I'd like to cluster standard errors at multiple levels in R using survey weights. Am I right that Lumley's survey package does not do this? In reprex below, svyglm with clustering at one and two levels have same standard errors. Any ideas?

```
library(survey) 

data(api)

dclus0<-svydesign(id=~1, weights=~pw, data=apiclus2) # no clustering
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus2) # clustering at one level
dclus2<-svydesign(id=~dnum+snum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus2) # clustering at two levels

summary(svyglm(api00~ell+meals+mobility, design=dclus0)) # no clustering
summary(svyglm(api00~ell+meals+mobility, design=dclus1)) # clustering at one level
summary(svyglm(api00~ell+meals+mobility, design=dclus2)) # clustering at two levels
```

Comment: This is perhaps useful, from the `svydesign` function documentation. "The population size for each level of sampling should also be specified in fpc. If fpc is not specified then sampling is assumed to be with replacement at the top level and only the first stage of cluster is used in computing variances."

Comment: might just be too much overlap in the variable you've chosen?  standard errors are different with `~stype` and `~both+stype`

Comment: ***update: R (svyglm) and STATA (ivrobust2 and cluster2 functions) produce very similar standard errors with *data that are nested in typical fashion*, e.g., student scores nested within classrooms nested within schools. However, they disagree when things are slightly more complicated: e.g., in my data, individual survey respondents were each given a random selection of 20 news headlines (from about 100 headlines) and answered one question about each. So I have responses nested within respondents and news headlines.

Comment: other than the fact STATA and svyglm won't produce the same results, another indication something weird is going on: svyglm indicates the wrong number of clusters:

"2 - level Cluster Sampling design (with replacement)
With (59, 8647) clusters."

59 = number of headlines, but 8647 is not the number of respondents. instead, it's the *number of respondents multiplied by 20 (the number of headlines each respondent rated)*

Comment: and here's what my survey design object looks like: svydesign(id=~hdl_id + id, weights = ~weight, 
          data = long)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have my doubts about 8647 being the number of respondents multiplied by 20, but, ok, missing data or something.

If it were nested, and sampling without replacement, as you told `svydesign`, getting the same standard errors for those two analyses would be correct.  And the numbers (59, 8647) would also be correct: 59 sampling units at stage 1, 8647 sampling units at stage 2.

You (I think) have data where two observations are correlated if either they share a participant or they share a headline. This design is not nested, it's crossed: participant 1 for headline 1 is the same person as participant 1 for headline 2.

I actually wrote standard error estimation code in R for this so long ago that CRAN didn't exist: the code is [here](https://faculty.washington.edu/tlumley/weave.html), and the function is called `xeffect.glm`. I think it's the same approach that was later independently invented and put in `-cluster2-` in Stata.  The code is for `glm` objects, but it allows for weights, so put the sampling weights in as weights in the `glm` to get the point estimates, then feed the resulting `glm` objects to `xeffect.glm`

As an additional historical note: the rest of the code at that link was reimplemented in the `sandwich` package by Achim Zeileis, but the crossed-effects estimator wasn't, because he was mainly interested in time-series.

Comment: This works perfectly for me (is replicating with STATA IVREG2). Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! You could maybe accept the answer?

Comment: oops, yes! Done! Thanks again Thomas!

Comment: Just to note this is implemented in `sandwich` using `sandwich::vcovCL(., cadjust = FALSE)`. It accepts an arbitrary number of clustering variables. I get identical results using `xeffect.glm()` and `vcovCL()`.